# Simple div disposition issue

Tags: css

Simple question: I've got two divs, I want them side by side, like this:

```css
.details-left {
   background: yellow;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.details-right {
   background: silver; 
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="details-left">left</div>
<div class="details-right">right</div>
```

The question is, can I have the same effect using `float` in only one if the divs? The specific issue is, the yellow div can contain `float: left`, the silver div can't. I want to achieve the same effect without using `float` on the silver div.

How can I achieve it?

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rts6okb/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` to achieve what you want.

```css
.details-left {
   background: yellow;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.details-right {
   background: silver; 
    width: 50%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="details-left">left</div>
<div class="details-right">right</div>
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5rts6okb/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: inline-block` for the silver div

http://jsfiddle.net/94Lxd5c4/

```
.details-right {
    background: silver; 
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

---

Or you may just define `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow: auto;` . The behaviour of the silver div will be the same, whether you add `float: left` or not (it won't do any difference)

http://jsfiddle.net/ogwvjjs9/2/

```
.details-right {
    background: silver; 
    width: 50%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Fabrizio, I accepted Kawinesh's answer as he was faster to reply. However, I upvoted because, not only your answer is correct too, but also because your second suggestion intrigues me. I would have never thought of using "overflow" and I still don't understand it. It works perfectly and adds the possibility of not defining the width of the right div as it will stretch based on the width of the left div, eg, if the left div is 30%, the right will fill the remaining 70% perfectly. Would you care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.details-left {
   background: yellow;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.details-right {
   background: silver; 
    width: 50%;
    position : absolute;
    left : 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="details-left">left</div>
<div class="details-right">right</div>
```

I hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` to achieve your need.

I added one more div that will act as a **table**

**< div class="details">**

Below div act as a **table cell**

**< div class="details-left">left< /div>**

**< div class="details-right">right< /div>**

```
<div class="details">
<div class="details-left">left</div>
<div class="details-right">right</div>
</div>
```

html

```
.details { display:table; width:100%; overflow:hidden;}
.details-left {
   background: yellow;
   display:table-cell;
   width: 50%;
}

.details-right {
   background: silver; 
    width: 50%;
   display:table-cell;
}
```

css

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ravinthranath/skuvnvqL/

Comment: Why `overflow: hidden` on the `details` div?

Comment: overflow:hidden act as a container for both left and right div @chiapa

Comment: I'm not asking about the details div, I'm asking why do you have `overflow: hidden` there. If you remove it, the effect is the same, right?

Comment: Inside the details div , u have little bit of details, so no need overflow:hiddden, but its needed for large div... @chiapa

Comment: If you are using position : absolute;, that will affect on responsive design, so better to use this... it will not break your code at the time of making responsive @chiapa